# PHP new PDO Connection Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I run a game forum and associated game server.  For the last 2 years, users signed up on the forums, which had their name/password then passed to my game servers database.  Once they completed registration, another call was made that flipped a flag in the game database to allow them to play.

At some point, this process stopped working and all new forum accounts (phpbb forums) simply never made their way to my games SQL servers.  I've opened up my SQL monitor on my game server and no connection is ever made using the credentials that have been passed.  I also get no error listed when a new account is created.  Code below:

```
// Create game account

try {
$acctConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DB_Redacted;host=x.x.x.x;port=33306;charset=utf8','DB_forum','PasswordHere', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$acctStmt = $acctConnection->prepare('CALL forum_link(?,?)');
$acctStmt->bindParam(1, $newname);
$acctStmt->bindParam(2, $plainpassword);
$acctStmt->execute();
$acctConnection = NULL;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Creating game account failed';
}
```

forum_link is the stored procedure used to insert the values in to the game database.  The account is also setup to only accept connections from my dedicated IP forum host, which the IP has not changed and also to be able to run the stored procedure listed.  Game server is listening on the listed port and I've even tested with no firewall running.  I'm fairly new to this as the process was setup by another dev who no longer works on the project but was seemingly working without fail for a long time.  Any ideas what may be wrong and/or how I can get more robust logging in place to catch what the issue may be?

Comment: Have a look at the error logs.

Comment: Nothing gets logged, unfortunately.  I was thinking of pulling out this section and testing just connectivity but I'm worried the logging that's in place either isn't correct or isn't being displayed for whatever reason.

Comment: *Everything* gets logged unless the person who setup your server was a bozo.

Comment: Why is this tagged sql-server? Also, can you post the stored procedure code? Try testing the SP in your MySQL console. And also, does a PDO exception appear in `try/catch`?

Comment: The SP works fine and I can run it from my game server to manually add accounts.  The post is tagged as SQL as I feel like this may be a SQL to SQL connection issue but I'm looking to find out if that is true via finding some way to capture the error, should there be one, that gets thrown.

I'm unfamiliar with try/catch, how does that work and/or how is that implemented?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue where the PDO function was corrupt/missing due to Java being corrupt on the webserver.  This was due to a hosting issue.  I reset this by selecting a new (updated) java version to be used in CPANEL, which reinstalled the PDO module and my connections to the other SQL server then had no problems.  I needed to add additional error logging to my PDO statement to catch this as being the issue, which I found how to do via some webdevs elsewhere.